# How to implement despeckle in OpenCV?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, image-manipulation

If histogram equalization is done on a poorly-contrasted image then its features become more visible. However there is also a large amount of grains/speckles/noise. using blurring functions already available in OpenCV is not desirable - i'll be doing text-detection on the image later on and the letters will get unrecognizable.
 So what are the preprocessing techniques that should be applied?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Standard blur techniques that convolve the image with a kernel (e.g. Gaussian blur, box filter, etc) act as a low-pass filter and distort the high-frequency text. If you have not done so already, try `cv::bilateralFilter()` or `cv::medianBlur()`. If neither of these algorithms work, you should look into other *edge-preserving smoothing algorithms*.

If you imagine the image as a three-dimensional space, traditional filtering replaces the value of each pixel with the weighted average of all filters in a circle centered around the pixel. Bilateral filtering does the same, but uses a three-dimensional sphere centered at the pixel. Since a well-defined edge looks like a plateau, the sphere contains only one point and the pixel value remains unchanged. You can get a more detailed explanation of the bilateral filter and some sample output [here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/MANDUCHI1/Bilateral_Filtering.html).