# How to remove noise from a histogram equalized image?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I have an image which I'm equalizing and then using clahe histogram on, like so:

```
self.equ = cv2.equalizeHist(self.result_array)
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=100.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
self.cl1 = clahe.apply(self.equ)
```

This is the result I get:

[image]

I want to get rid of all the black dots which is noise. Ultimately, I'm trying to extract out the blood vessels, which are black in the image shown above, in trying to do so, the noise makes the extraction inaccurate.

Comment: the noise looks to be nicely high contrast, you just need to apply a despeckle process.  Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680429/how-to-implement-despeckle-in-opencv

Comment: might be easier to reduce the noise in the non-hist-equalized image.

Comment: If this noise is not present in the original image, it is an artifact of the equalization. You can try options like Gamma correction and contrast stretching. Also, the Frangi filter is usually used to extract vessel-like structures.

Comment: @dhanushka, is there a python implementation of Frangi filter?

Comment: @Micka, what kind of blurring would you suggest for that?

Comment: @stack don't know about a python implementation. google search lists Matlab implementation. Also there's a ImageJ [plugin](http://imagej.net/Frangi). If you are interested, you can first try it with ImageJ and see how it performs before going into any implementations.

Comment: try median blur, gaussian blur, or some edge preserving blur like bilateral filtering

Comment: Why would you do a histogram eq, and then a CLAHE? Can I get the original image to play around with? Will all images have that blur down the middle? You can try blurring the image quite a bit, find an average of an empty area without blood vessels and then treshold the image with that value. Possibly dilatation and erosion operators could help you remove some of the points before you blur. SO has a series of these questions whose answers usually point to so-called Frangi filter: http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0056195. This is all, of course, quite a bit of work for a general case.

Comment: can you please provide a lossless compressed image like .png instead of a .jpg (those have artifacts), if you can?

Comment: @Micka, done. Just made an edit.

Comment: Strictly talking - for 2D images you can use mean/median filtering to remove that kind of noise. However that also mean removing some information.

Comment: Just for kicks I would try using an opening operation on it. http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/plugins/gray-morphology.html

Answer (score 2):

A large part of my thesis was on reducing the noise in images, and there was a technique I used which reduced noise in images while preserving the sharp edges of information in the image. I quote myself here:

> An effective technique for removing noise from fringe patterns is to filter the image
>   using sine-cosine filtering [[reference]](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0030401899001169). A low-pass filter is convolved with the two images that
>   result from taking the sine and cosine of the fringe pattern image, which are then
>   divided to obtain the tangent, restoring the phase pattern but with reduced noise. The
>   advantage of this technique is that the process can be repeated multiple times to
>   reduce noise while maintaining the sharp details of the phase transitions.

And here is the code I used:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

def scfilter(image, iterations, kernel):
    """
    Sine‐cosine filter.
    kernel can be tuple or single value.
    Returns filtered image.
    """
    for n in range(iterations):
        image = np.arctan2(
        ndimage.filters.uniform_filter(np.sin(image), size=kernel),
        ndimage.filters.uniform_filter(np.cos(image), size=kernel))
    return image
```

There, `image` was a numpy array representing the image, linearly rescaled to put black at `0` and white at `2 * pi`, and `kernel` is the size in image pixels of the uniform filter applied to the data. It shouldn't take too many iterations to see a positive result, maybe in the region of 5 to 20.

Hope that helps :)